# What is the use of short frame title

Tags: beamer, presentations, frame-title

In most of the time, we only specify the long frame-title as `\frametitle{My long title}`.

But if we type `\frametitle[short]{My long title}` then what is the use of this short title? We can see the use of short titles for sections, title, etc. But I don't see where this short frame title is useful.

Comment: Is this related to LaTeX? It seems to be a question asking whether we should use short titles or not.

Comment: @JouleV The syntax for frame title is `\frametitle[short frame title]{title}`. What is this short frame title is for?

Comment: So are you asking how the short title works?

Comment: Yes. If I specify it in a frame, where is it going to appear?

Answer (score 2):

Documentation of `beamer`, page 75:

[image]

So...

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Hello, world!}

\insertshortframetitle

Hello, universe! \insertshortframetitle
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Something like that.